# Difference of a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Maybe someone can help me with this..

Given this sequence:

$$f_n=\frac{f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}}{2},$$

$$f_0=0, f_1=1$$
Find an explicit formula for the difference:
$$F_n:=f_n-f_{n-1}$$

I have the solution but I don't understand one step. The solution is:
$$F_n:=f_n-f_{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}(f_{n-1}+f_{n-2})-f_{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}(-f_{n-1}+f_{n-2})=-\frac{1}{2}F_{n-1}
\\it follows\\
F_n=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}F_1
=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}(f_1-f_0)=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$

The step that I didn't understand is:
$$F_n=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}F_1$$
How do I get there? They write in the answers sheet it follows but from what and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep applying the recurrence $F_n=-\frac12F_{n-1}$:

$$\begin{align*}
F_n&=-\frac12F_{n-1}\\
&=-\frac12\left(-\frac12F_{n-2}\right)\\
&=\left(-\frac12\right)^2F_{n-2}\\
&=\left(-\frac12\right)^2\left(-\frac12F_{n-3}\right)\\
&=\left(-\frac12\right)^3F_{n-3}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=\left(-\frac12\right)^kF_{n-k}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}F_{n-(n-1)}\\
&=\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}F_1
\end{align*}$$

If still in doubt, you can then prove it by induction on $n$.

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, solving the auxiliary  equation $2x^2-x-1$ gives roots $1,-\frac12$ so the solution is
$$
f_n=A+B(-\frac12)^n
$$
and the values for $n=0,1$ show that $A=\frac23,B=-\frac23$. consequently:
$$
F_n=(-\frac23)\left( \left( -\frac12 \right)^n -\left( -\frac12 \right)^{n-1} \right) \\
=\left( - \frac12 \right)^{n-1}
$$