# Limit of 2 variable function. Does it exist? Why?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Given a function $f$ defined on the set $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \mid x\neq 1\}$.
 Does this limit exist?

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}\frac{y}{x-1}
$$

I procede in this way taking these 2 lines
$$
\{ (x,y)\mid y=0, x\neq1 \}
$$
the limit here should be $0$. While here
$$y=x-1$$
the limit is $1$. This line goes through the point $(1,0)$.
Therefore the limit doesn't exist. But why?

Should every line/function cross the point inserted in the $f$ function to have the same limit?

What is the visual explanation of what is happening?

Comment: What is your initial guess about it?

Comment: Note that, by $x-1=u$, $y=v$ the limit is equivalent to $$\lim_{(u,v)\to(0,0)} \frac v u$$

Comment: It would be useful if you can explain what your thoughts are about that and what you have already tried.

Comment: The question is well edited and decribed but it would be very useful if could add some detail more on what your work has been on it up to now. Any idea?

Comment: Do not discourage for the downvotes, please update the OP with the requested information and let me know if you can reach your own conclusions from the given hint.

Comment: You should elaborate something similar to your previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1584984/505767)

Comment: Well done! I add something on the point you have raised after editing.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed if we consider the following paths

- $x\neq 1$, $y=0$
- $x=1+t$, $y=t$ with $t\to 0$

we obtain to different values for the limit.

Now it can be shown that when the limit exist it is unique therefore whenever we can find different paths with different limit we can conclude that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Or $x=1+t^2,y=t$ with $t\to 0$ for the first. Gives a nice contrast with the second.

Comment: @Deepak Yes of course! We have many good choices here! :)

Comment: Indeed. Why did someone downvote you? I'll upvote to compensate.

Comment: @Deepak I don't understand why, maybe because they consider those kind of questions too much elementary or not well posed to deserve attention? Anyway that's not a big problem for me, my aim is to give some useful help to the asker. Thanks a lot for your kind support! Cheers